# Vim FuzzyFinder FufTag for current active buffer

Tags: vim, textmate, fuzzyfinder

I would like to jump to a tag (function) in the current active buffer with completion search like FuzzyFinder's functionality. The FufTag function from FuzzyFinder lists all the tags in the project and I only want the tags from the current active buffer.  Is there a way to set up FuzzyFinder to do both or is there another plugin that does this?

I would like this functionality for PHP. Thanks

Something similar asked here: [TextMate's Jump to Function in VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618337/textmates-jump-to-function-in-vim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created a feature request and it has been implemented in Fuzzyfinder.
[The ticket](https://bitbucket.org/ns9tks/vim-fuzzyfinder/issue/25/fuftag-for-current-active-buffer#comment-257702)